# Second monitor in X server PRIME profile "On-demand"

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, gpu, xserver, nvidia-prime

Recently the new PRIME profile "NVIDIA On-Demand" has been added which apparently uses the NVIDIA GPU when needed for demanding software. However, when I activate it my second screen does not work anymore. I can, however, see it listed in the X server settings when I plug it in in that mode.

Is there a way to enable the second screen in "On-Demand" mode?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Ubuntu.